# How can I start and stop a MySQL Event in a Day

Tags: mysql

I want to create an event which will start at 09:00 and Stops at 22:00.
and executes on every five minutes.

Is it possible to stop the event at 22:00 every day
and start 9:00 next day.

Comment: read more about even scheduler http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MySQL Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) for this purpose but don't think you can explicitely stop the event likewise you are talking about. One example:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
    DO
      UPDATE table1 SET col1 = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create an event that calls a procedure called myEvent() every 5 minutes**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE 
    EVENT `name_of_event` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
    DO BEGIN
    CALL myEvent();
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**In myEvent(): Check if time is between 09:00:00 and 22:00:00**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE myEvent()
BEGIN
IF((DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%H:%m:%s') BETWEEN '09:00:00' AND '22:00:00') THEN
// Do your stuff
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```